# Plotting a rectangle in 3D space in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

Suppose I have four points as

```
p1 = [x1,y1,z];
p2 = [x2,y2,z];
p3 = [x3,y3,z];
p4 = [x4,y4,z];
```

If these four points form a rectangle, what line of code should I write to plot this rectangle in 3D space in Matlab?

Thanks.

Comment: the answer you can find: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599561/plot-square-surface-in-matlab/19606870#19606870)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to take away all doubt about differences between a rectangular/square surface or set of lines; here's how to plot just the perimeter of the rectangle:

```
>> p = [p1;p2;p3;p4; p1];
>> line(p(:,1), p(:,2), p(:,3))
```

Comment: Thanks!!was of great help..